# DIV position:fixed - overflow issue

Tags: html, css, position, overflow, fixed

I have such problem: in "parent" DIV I added DIV with (class="float") with position: fixed. You can see it on my demo page (right sidebar): http://1stsept.cba.pl/faq.html

I've two problems:
1) second DIV (float) is widther than "parent" DIV - is any possibility to solve it?
2) Much more important: when I'm scrooling page to the bottom, the floating DIV is overlaping on footer bar (black). How to prevent it (stop DIV in the end of sidebar) (screenshot: http://img18.imageshack.us/img18/7489/8nyy.png)?

I don't know JavaScript so please help me step-by-step :)
Sorry for my English
I hope to your help,
Regards

Comment: Can you provide some code and/or jsFiddle of the issue?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know jsFiddle :( Here you have "demo" page with described problem(s): http://1stsept.cba.pl/faq.html. I don't know which part of css/html/js code may generate problem so I'm presenting you "all" :(

Comment: It is hard for me to be specific without reading your actual code. Make sure your floated DIVs and their container elements have position: attributes specified in the CSS. You also need to specify a width to any floated element. Also, I believe you will need to add clear:both; to your footer CSS. Here are pages that might help you better understand the float property: http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/ and http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/

Comment: I tried and added clear:both - nothing happen :( Stiil position:fixed DIV is overcoming on footer.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the first problem:
You can easily fix it by specifying the width of inner div since the sidebar has fixed width.

```
<div class="float" style="width: 175px">
```

or define the width in CSS class.

Comment: I have procentage witdth = so instead of px I try use %.
Thank you.

But what can I do with overlaping on footer? It's ugly :( (here screen: http://img18.imageshack.us/img18/7489/8nyy.png)